# Deserialize generic class into dynamic c#

Tags: c#, file, generics, serialization, dynamic

I currently have a generic class in an archive as a serialized file. I do not know what what type it is, only that it is this generic class. For testing purposes I do know that this specific file is a short.

```
PeriodV2<T> meta = new PeriodV2<T>()
```

Where T = Short / 16bit int for this example

So I'm trying now to deserialize the file as a dynamic PeriodV2, This however causes an error on the deserialize operation.

```
public PeriodV2<dynamic> GetPeriod (string path)
{
    PeriodV2<dynamic> pm;

    using (var inStream = File.OpenRead(path))
    using (ZipFile zipfile = new ZipFile(inStream))
    using (Stream zipinputstream = zipfile.GetInputStream(zipfile.GetEntry("period.meta")))
        pm = (PeriodV2<dynamic>)_bf.Deserialize(zipinputstream);

    pm.ArchivePath = path;
    return pm;
}
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Forecaster.Core.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'Forecaster.Core.PeriodV2'1[System.Int16]' to type
>   'Forecaster.Core.PeriodV2'1[System.Object]'.

So how would I be able to deserialize this regardless of the type of PeriodV2 it is?

Comment: `PeriodV2<dynamic>` is a different type to `PeriodV2<int>` so you can't cast like this.

Comment: I don't think you can deserialize unless you know what's the type you're converting to. It had a type before and it should have a type after deserialization, the same set of bytes can have  a different meaning for a whole bunch of different types

Comment: As dissatisfying as answer is, it at least confirms what I was already worried of, meaning that I can start looking for alternative sollutions